# Can we build a planet with a hyperbolic surface?

Tags: alternate-reality, alien-geometry

The hyperbolic plane has some [fascinating story potential](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/103368/how-to-navigate-the-hyperbolic-world), but just declaring that your story takes place on a hyperbolic plane seems like a clear fantasy, with all the same kinds of problems that come from a world that's just an infinite flat Euclidean plane. Not that there's anything inherently wrong with such settings in fantasy, but I'd like to be a little more rigorous. For example, an infinite plane of matter with gravity is unstable and would have a tendency to break apart and re-form into spheres seeded by density anomalies (e.g., mountains), and the same is true for a hyperbolic plane. It would be nicer if we could come up with a surface that is stable.

My first thought was "just put a planet in a hyperbolic universe"... but it turns out that [spheres in hyperbolic space still have positive surface curvature](https://www.quora.com/Do-spheres-in-hyperbolic-space-still-have-positive-Gaussian-curvature/answer/Eryk-Kopczynski). So while an otherwise-normal hyperbolic universe does have some interesting properties, and a planet with a very small radius in such a place could have an absolutely *enormous* surface area, that enormous surface nevertheless ends up looking to people walking around on it like a perfectly normal planetary surface with spherical geometry, which merely happens to be embedded in a hyperbolic universe.

So, how, and in what sort of universe, could we build a stable planet (or anti-planet--a living surface around which a light source orbits, rather than the other way around), held together by gravity, whose surface has negative curvature?

Comment: A more exotic possibility is to look at spaces with indefinite signature (Minkowskian/de Sitter/anti-de Sitter) instead of the usual Euclidean/spherical/hyperbolic spaces. For example, in the story [Dichronauts](https://www.gregegan.net/DICHRONAUTS/DICHRONAUTS.html) by Greg Egan the planet's surface is naturally shaped like a hyperboloid of one sheet. If I'm not mistaken, its curvature is still positive, but if it were a hyperboloid of *two* sheets (or one of its halves) it would have constant negative curvature (this can happen because it's embedded in a Minkowskian space).

Comment: @pregunton The surface on which the main characters originate is a negatively-curved (but with very large characteristic length, so the hyperbolicity doesn't matter much) hyperboloid of one sheet, but they visit (half of) a hyperboloid of two sheets in the "underland".

Comment: "In what sort of universe" kinda violates the book rule. As much fun as various authors have had dealing with (e.g.) hyperbolic planets, the reality (I'm pretty sure, but I could be wrong) is that you'd need a universe that permitted gravity expressed, from our perspective, in imaginary numbers. Is that enough to answer your question, or do you need all the rest of the details (that authors tend to ignore) such as how to express the speed of light, Maxwell's equations, etc., in a universe that permitted gravity to be expressed with imaginary numbers? Can you narrow the scope of your question?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can have an enclosed volume with a hyperbolic surface, if it is to enclose itself then it must on a macro level have negative curvature. However you can have surfaces that are locally hyperbolic.

You would end up with surfaces with [lots of folds and wrinkles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry#Physical_realizations_of_the_hyperbolic_plane). However because this local hyperbolicity is on the surface of a sphere the center of mass would be towards the center of the planet, not tangential to the local surface.

If you want to follow physical rules something will be needed to keep the folds from collapsing. This would give you very weird terrain but it would still be a sphere of stuff orbiting a star.

Or, ignore the physics, set your world on a hyperbolic surface, have gravity be weird, and figure out something to do with the sun, because that's a damn fantastic setting to play about in.